# How to display only the specific data from the list of database content in indexed db using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, indexeddb

I got an IndexedDB Demo: storing blobs, e-publication example code in plunker . It is actually similar to the work that I'm doing now . And here is the output image of that code[image]

And here if you observe the output shows all the List of database content at a time because the example code has used this highlighted part 
i.e

[image].

Which shows all the data at a time.

But what I'm trying to do is to show only the specific data from the database by creating the table.

**For ex** : If I fill all the text-boxes also i should be able to display only the specific data that I choose.

And Here is the code .

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Template:CustomSampleCSS?raw=1" />

<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

form {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

input {
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.required:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}

.button-pane {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#pub-viewer {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  height: 20em;
  border: solid #d092ff 0.1em;
}
#pub-viewer iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#pub-list {
  width: 46%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
#pub-list li {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

#msg {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.action-success {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #00d21e;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.action-failure {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #ff1408;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.note {
  font-size: smaller;
}

.destructive {
  background-color: orange;
}
.destructive:hover {
  background-color: #ff8000;
}
.destructive:active {
  background-color: red;
}
    </style>         
   </head>
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    

        <h1>IndexedDB Demo: storing blobs, e-publication example</h1>
        <div class="note">
      <p>
        Works and tested with:
      </p>
      <div id="compat">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="msg">
    </div>

    <form id="register-form">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-title" class="required">
                Title:
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="pub-title" name="pub-title" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-biblioid" class="required">
                Bibliographic ID:<br/>
                <span class="note">(ISBN, ISSN, etc.)</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="pub-biblioid" name="pub-biblioid"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-year">
                Year:
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="pub-year" name="pub-year" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-file">
                File image:
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="file" id="pub-file"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-file-url">
                Online-file image URL:<br/>
                <span class="note">(same origin URL)</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="pub-file-url" name="pub-file-url"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="button-pane">
        <input type="button" id="add-button" value="Add Publication" />
        <input type="reset" id="register-form-reset"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <form id="delete-form">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pub-biblioid-to-delete">
                Bibliographic ID:<br/>
                <span class="note">(ISBN, ISSN, etc.)</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="pub-biblioid-to-delete"
                     name="pub-biblioid-to-delete" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="key-to-delete">
                Key:<br/>
                <span class="note">(for example 1, 2, 3, etc.)</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="key-to-delete"
                     name="key-to-delete" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="button-pane">
        <input type="button" id="delete-button" value="Delete Publication" />
        <input type="button" id="clear-store-button"
               value="Clear the whole store" class="destructive" />
      </div>
    </form>

    <form id="search-form">
      <div class="button-pane">
        <input type="button" id="search-list-button"
               value="List database content" />
      </div>
    </form>

    <div>
      <div id="pub-msg">
      </div>
      <div id="pub-viewer">
      </div>
      <ul id="pub-list">
      </ul>
    </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
  var COMPAT_ENVS = [
    ['Firefox', ">= 16.0"],
    ['Google Chrome',
     ">= 24.0 (you may need to get Google Chrome Canary), NO Blob storage support"]
  ];
  var compat = $('#compat');
  compat.empty();
  compat.append('<ul id="compat-list"></ul>');
  COMPAT_ENVS.forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
    $('#compat-list').append('<li>' + val[0] + ': ' + val[1] + '</li>');
  });

  const DB_NAME = 'mdn-demo-indexeddb-epublications';
  const DB_VERSION = 1; // Use a long long for this value (don't use a float)
  const DB_STORE_NAME = 'publications';

  var db;

  // Used to keep track of which view is displayed to avoid uselessly reloading it
  var current_view_pub_key;

  function openDb() {
    console.log("openDb ...");
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
      // Better use "this" than "req" to get the result to avoid problems with
      // garbage collection.
      // db = req.result;
      db = this.result;
      console.log("openDb DONE");
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
      console.log("openDb.onupgradeneeded");
      var store = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
        DB_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });

      store.createIndex('biblioid', 'biblioid', { unique: true });
      store.createIndex('title', 'title', { unique: false });
      store.createIndex('year', 'year', { unique: false });
    };
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} store_name
   * @param {string} mode either "readonly" or "readwrite"
   */
  function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
    var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
    return tx.objectStore(store_name);
  }

  function clearObjectStore(store_name) {
    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    var req = store.clear();
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      displayActionSuccess("Store cleared");
      displayPubList(store);
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("clearObjectStore:", evt.target.errorCode);
      displayActionFailure(this.error);
    };
  }

  function getBlob(key, store, success_callback) {
    var req = store.get(key);
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      var value = evt.target.result;
      if (value)
        success_callback(value.blob);
    };
  }

  /**
   * @param {IDBObjectStore=} store
   */
  function displayPubList(store) {
    console.log("displayPubList");

    if (typeof store == 'undefined')
      store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');

    var pub_msg = $('#pub-msg');
    pub_msg.empty();
    var pub_list = $('#pub-list');

    pub_list.empty();
    // Resetting the iframe so that it doesn't display previous content
    newViewerFrame();

    var req;
    req = store.count();
    // Requests are executed in the order in which they were made against the
    // transaction, and their results are returned in the same order.
    // Thus the count text below will be displayed before the actual pub list
    // (not that it is algorithmically important in this case).
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      pub_msg.append('<p>There are <strong>' + evt.target.result +
                     '</strong> record(s) in the object store.</p>');
    };
    req.onerror = function(evt) {
      console.error("add error", this.error);
      displayActionFailure(this.error);
    };

    var i = 0;
    req = store.openCursor();
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      var cursor = evt.target.result;

      // If the cursor is pointing at something, ask for the data
      if (cursor) {
        console.log("displayPubList cursor:", cursor);
        req = store.get(cursor.key);
        req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
          var value = evt.target.result;
          var list_item = $('<li>' +
                            '[' + cursor.key + '] ' +
                            '(biblioid: ' + value.biblioid + ') ' +
                            value.title +
                            '</li>');
          if (value.year != null)
            list_item.append(' - ' + value.year);

          if (value.hasOwnProperty('blob') &&
              typeof value.blob != 'undefined') {
            var link = $('<a href="' + cursor.key + '">File</a>');
            link.on('click', function() { return false; });
            link.on('mouseenter', function(evt) {
                      setInViewer(evt.target.getAttribute('href')); });
            list_item.append(' / ');
            list_item.append(link);
          } else {
            list_item.append(" / No attached file");
          }
          pub_list.append(list_item);
        };

        // Move on to the next object in store
        cursor.continue();

        // This counter serves only to create distinct ids
        i++;
      } else {
        console.log("No more entries");
      }
    };
  }

  function newViewerFrame() {
    var viewer = $('#pub-viewer');
    viewer.empty();
    var iframe = $('<iframe />');
    viewer.append(iframe);
    return iframe;
  }

  function setInViewer(key) {
    console.log("setInViewer:", arguments);
    key = Number(key);
    if (key == current_view_pub_key)
      return;

    current_view_pub_key = key;

    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');
    getBlob(key, store, function(blob) {
      console.log("setInViewer blob:", blob);
      var iframe = newViewerFrame();

      // It is not possible to set a direct link to the
      // blob to provide a mean to directly download it.
      if (blob.type == 'text/html') {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(evt) {
          var html = evt.target.result;
          iframe.load(function() {
            $(this).contents().find('html').html(html);
          });
        });
        reader.readAsText(blob);
      } else if (blob.type.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
        iframe.load(function() {
          var img_id = 'image-' + key;
          var img = $('<img id="' + img_id + '"/>');
          $(this).contents().find('body').html(img);
          var obj_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          $(this).contents().find('#' + img_id).attr('src', obj_url);
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(obj_url);
        });
      } else if (blob.type == 'application/pdf') {
        $('*').css('cursor', 'wait');
        var obj_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        iframe.load(function() {
          $('*').css('cursor', 'auto');
        });
        iframe.attr('src', obj_url);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(obj_url);
      } else {
        iframe.load(function() {
          $(this).contents().find('body').html("No view available");
        });
      }

    });
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} biblioid
   * @param {string} title
   * @param {number} year
   * @param {string} url the URL of the image to download and store in the local
   *   IndexedDB database. The resource behind this URL is subjected to the
   *   "Same origin policy", thus for this method to work, the URL must come from
   *   the same origin as the web site/app this code is deployed on.
   */
  function addPublicationFromUrl(biblioid, title, year, url) {
    console.log("addPublicationFromUrl:", arguments);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    // Setting the wanted responseType to "blob"
    // http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-response-attribute
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function (evt) {
                           if (xhr.status == 200) {
                             console.log("Blob retrieved");
                             var blob = xhr.response;
                             console.log("Blob:", blob);
                             addPublication(biblioid, title, year, blob);
                           } else {
                             console.error("addPublicationFromUrl error:",
                                           xhr.responseText, xhr.status);
                           }
                         };
    xhr.send();

    // We can't use jQuery here because as of jQuery 1.8.3 the new "blob"
    // responseType is not handled.
    // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461
    // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7248
    // $.ajax({
    //   url: url,
    //   type: 'GET',
    //   xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
    //   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //     console.log("Blob retrieved");
    //     console.log("Blob:", data);
    //     // addPublication(biblioid, title, year, data);
    //   },
    //   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //     console.error(errorThrown);
    //     displayActionFailure("Error during blob retrieval");
    //   }
    // });
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} biblioid
   * @param {string} title
   * @param {number} year
   * @param {Blob=} blob
   */
  function addPublication(biblioid, title, year, blob) {
    console.log("addPublication arguments:", arguments);
    var obj = { biblioid: biblioid, title: title, year: year };
    if (typeof blob != 'undefined')
      obj.blob = blob;

    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    var req;
    try {
      req = store.add(obj);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name == 'DataCloneError')
        displayActionFailure("This engine doesn't know how to clone a Blob, " +
                             "use Firefox");
      throw e;
    }
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
      console.log("Insertion in DB successful");
      displayActionSuccess();
      displayPubList(store);
    };
    req.onerror = function() {
      console.error("addPublication error", this.error);
      displayActionFailure(this.error);
    };
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} biblioid
   */
  function deletePublicationFromBib(biblioid) {
    console.log("deletePublication:", arguments);
    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    var req = store.index('biblioid');
    req.get(biblioid).onsuccess = function(evt) {
      if (typeof evt.target.result == 'undefined') {
        displayActionFailure("No matching record found");
        return;
      }
      deletePublication(evt.target.result.id, store);
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("deletePublicationFromBib:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };
  }

  /**
   * @param {number} key
   * @param {IDBObjectStore=} store
   */
  function deletePublication(key, store) {
    console.log("deletePublication:", arguments);

    if (typeof store == 'undefined')
      store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');

    // As per spec http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-deletion-operation
    // the result of the Object Store Deletion Operation algorithm is
    // undefined, so it's not possible to know if some records were actually
    // deleted by looking at the request result.
    var req = store.get(key);
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      var record = evt.target.result;
      console.log("record:", record);
      if (typeof record == 'undefined') {
        displayActionFailure("No matching record found");
        return;
      }
      // Warning: The exact same key used for creation needs to be passed for
      // the deletion. If the key was a Number for creation, then it needs to
      // be a Number for deletion.
      req = store.delete(key);
      req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        console.log("evt:", evt);
        console.log("evt.target:", evt.target);
        console.log("evt.target.result:", evt.target.result);
        console.log("delete successful");
        displayActionSuccess("Deletion successful");
        displayPubList(store);
      };
      req.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error("deletePublication:", evt.target.errorCode);
      };
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("deletePublication:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };
  }

  function displayActionSuccess(msg) {
    msg = typeof msg != 'undefined' ? "Success: " + msg : "Success";
    $('#msg').html('<span class="action-success">' + msg + '</span>');
  }
  function displayActionFailure(msg) {
    msg = typeof msg != 'undefined' ? "Failure: " + msg : "Failure";
    $('#msg').html('<span class="action-failure">' + msg + '</span>');
  }
  function resetActionStatus() {
    console.log("resetActionStatus ...");
    $('#msg').empty();
    console.log("resetActionStatus DONE");
  }

  function addEventListeners() {
    console.log("addEventListeners");

    $('#register-form-reset').click(function(evt) {
      resetActionStatus();
    });

    $('#add-button').click(function(evt) {
      console.log("add ...");
      var title = $('#pub-title').val();
      var biblioid = $('#pub-biblioid').val();
      if (!title || !biblioid) {
        displayActionFailure("Required field(s) missing");
        return;
      }
      var year = $('#pub-year').val();
      if (year != '') {
        // Better use Number.isInteger if the engine has EcmaScript 6
        if (isNaN(year))  {
          displayActionFailure("Invalid year");
          return;
        }
        year = Number(year);
      } else {
        year = null;
      }

      var file_input = $('#pub-file');
      var selected_file = file_input.get(0).files[0];
      console.log("selected_file:", selected_file);
      // Keeping a reference on how to reset the file input in the UI once we
      // have its value, but instead of doing that we rather use a "reset" type
      // input in the HTML form.
      //file_input.val(null);
      var file_url = $('#pub-file-url').val();
      if (selected_file) {
        addPublication(biblioid, title, year, selected_file);
      } else if (file_url) {
        addPublicationFromUrl(biblioid, title, year, file_url);
      } else {
        addPublication(biblioid, title, year);
      }

    });

    $('#delete-button').click(function(evt) {
      console.log("delete ...");
      var biblioid = $('#pub-biblioid-to-delete').val();
      var key = $('#key-to-delete').val();

      if (biblioid != '') {
        deletePublicationFromBib(biblioid);
      } else if (key != '') {
        // Better use Number.isInteger if the engine has EcmaScript 6
        if (key == '' || isNaN(key))  {
          displayActionFailure("Invalid key");
          return;
        }
        key = Number(key);
        deletePublication(key);
      }
    });

    $('#clear-store-button').click(function(evt) {
      clearObjectStore();
    });

    var search_button = $('#search-list-button');
    search_button.click(function(evt) {
      displayPubList();
    });

  }

  openDb();
  addEventListeners();

})(); // Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the plunker demo of the example code:-
[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oR3mqBf4MSDBdLribkCb?p=preview)

Please help me with this is because I'm confused a lot and I'm new to javascript . It will be helpful if you do this favour.